# How to disable keyboard suggestions in HiSense A5 Pro?

Tags: keyboard, customization

*HiSense A5 Pro, Android 10.*

When I am typing, just above keyboard section there is a row with possible completion/suggestions for the words I am typing in. I would like to disable this feature.

Is there a way to do it? I use English language in UI, but some parts of UI are still in Chinese.

Comment: I don't know about HiSense since it seems to use heavily-customized Android OS, but in general, the Settings app should have something like the Keyboard/Input setting, where the user can set and customize the virtual keyboard. At the very least, perhaps knowing the name of the keyboard app being used might help to determine if it's possible or not.

Comment: @AndrewT., there is keyboard section with several entries. There are three suspects out of them -- something in Chinese which leds to iFly panel (also in Chinese), when I disabled everything. Second is "physical keyboard" which leads to option for showing virtual keyboard (I disabled this as well), and Autofill service which I set to "none".

Comment: Hmm, without visualization of the menu, I'm afraid it's a bit hard to guess (not sure what "iFly panel" is, but "physical keyboard" and "autofill service" are unrelated). Also, I'm not sure if HiSense supports 3rd-party keyboard apps or not, because it's the alternative solution if the built-in keyboard doesn't have this setting...

Comment: @AndrewT. Sorry for that, here it is: https://photos.app.goo.gl/w3wXYVAkFeawhrRv7